# can we change or remove this for loop ( j=0; j < paras[i].childNodes.length; j++ )

Tags: javascript

[for reference purpose](http://www.elated.com/articles/looking-inside-dom-page-elements/)

I want to remove that second for loop and instead of using `childNodes[j]`, I want to go with `.firstChild`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
        function displayParas() {
          var output = "";
          var paras = document.getElementsByTagName( "p" );

          for ( i=0; i < paras.length; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j < paras[i].childNodes.length; j++ ) {
              if ( paras[i].childNodes[j].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ) {
                output += paras[i].childNodes[j].nodeValue + "\n";
              }
            }
          }

          alert( output );
        }
      // ]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Widget Company</h1>
```

My program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
        function displayParas() {
          var output = "";
          var paras = document.getElementsByTagName( "p" );

          for ( i=0; i < paras.length; i++ ) {
            if ( paras[i].firstChild.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ) {
                output += paras[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "\n";
              }
                else{
                  document.write(paras[i].firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue);
              }
            }
              alert( output );
          }


        }
      // ]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Widget Company</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the Widget Company!</p> 
    <p>We have lots of fantastic widgets for sale.</p>
    <p>Feel free to browse!</p>
    <p><a href="javascript:displayParas()">Display paragraph text</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

my output should look like this:

```
Welcome to the Widget Company!

We have lots of fantastic widgets for sale.

Feel free to browse!

Display paragraph text
```

But in second code nothing happens when I click on hyperlink.

Comment: well is the first child what you think it is? `console.log(paras[i].firstChild)`

Comment: and can someone explain why should i use childNodes[j] (an array) when paras[i].firstChild have only one value each. i.e why i want to remove that for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra "}" that is making your code fail.

```
 }
  // ]]>
</script>
```

the last one before the end of the script area